# How to remove blank row from my Matrix Visual in Power BI?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, measure, datamodel

I have a data model comprising tables like Calendar, Products, Returns, Sales, Customers, Products Category, Products Subcategory, and Territory. Sales and Returns are fact tables and others are dimension tables. I have calculated Total Orders. For that the used DAX is following -

Total Orders = Countrows(Values(Sales[Order Number]))

I have made another calculation as Sales Order for Jan to Feb in 2022.

Orders(Jan-Feb, 22) = Calculate(

```
                        [total orders],

                            Filter(

                               ALLNOBLANKROW(

                                    'Calendar'[Date]

                                   ),

                                and(
                                   'Calendar'[Date]>= date(2022,1,1),
                                    'Calendar'[Date]<=date(2022,2,28)
                                    )
                              )
                        )
```

Next, I have inserted a matrix. I have added Years and Month Name to Rows and Total Orders and Orders(Jan-Feb,22) to Values. After the addition of Orders(Jan-Feb, 22), matrix makes a blank row at the top. If I remove the measure, the blank row is also removed. At first I used All function in the measure. Blank row comes up. To remove it, I tried with ALLNOBLANKROW. But still the blank row persists. I cannot understand why it appears. I am going to attach a screenshot of my visuals.

[image: Blank row in the 2nd matrix]

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but I think if you select your matrix, then under filters uncheck 'blank' for Year, it would remove that row.